# Error on focused tests in Karma and Angular (failOnSkippedTests)

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Is there anyone here who has a working solution for the `failOnSkippedTests: true` flag in Karma testing with Angular?

I tried everything following by `https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3284`.
When I set focused test I got tests skipped and still success.

I've found in `node_modules\karma\lib\browser_collection.js` method `getResults()` which return `exitCode: 1` which is ok, so maybe the problem is in Reporter. I was trying to set `karma-spec-reporter` but it didn't work.

Any ideas, solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I use ESLint to lint the spec files with eslint-plugin-jasmine and when you lint the project, it will throw an error on a focused test.

You can find the plugin here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jasmine.

Comment: I use it too, but if it's a karma option then I'd like to use it :)